# r.watershed not completing task?

Tags: qgis-3

When executing ​the r.watershed ​command, you do ​not finish the ​procedure, ​staying in ​Section 2: A * ​Search, the ​module has not ​been finalized ​or killed. ​Someone can ​help give me a ​solution or an ​explanation why ​this error is ​due. In the ​attached image ​I show the ​properties of ​the raster with ​which the ​execution is ​worked.

I used qgis-3.6 and the ​parameter ​values used are 4x10^9 and enable disk swap memory option.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this on a smaller raster? If I read the metadata correctly this is about 60,000 x 40,000 cells. Crop your raster to something smaller (eg 600x400),  try running the algorithm, then try again at (1200x800) and (6000x4000) - see how long those take to predict the time for 60000x40000. That is a very large raster.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the suggestion, in fact I tried it before with another raster of smaller dimension 50000x30000 and executed correctly, I used lower threshold and I got many basins, now my problem is that I want to decrease that number of basins in this new raster and I never finish the task, I would like to identify the error. Thanks.